# Creating PHP -> XML with special character '&'

Tags: php, xml, encoding

I'm trying to create an XML from PHP with special characters.

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ' . 'standalone="yes"?><Root/>');

$data->addChild('NAME', $variable);

$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;     
$dom->formatOutput = true;
$dom->loadXML($xmlAusgabe = $xml->asXML());
$dom->save('../test.xml');
```

When there is a special character like '&' in it the output is empty.

I thought these characters are available in UTF-8.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Where is the ampersand (`&`)? I cannot see any in the question.

Comment: What's the point of `$dom->loadXML($xmlAusgabe = $xml->asXML());`? Use either [`SimpleXMLElement`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) or [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php), don't mix them. It doesn't hurt but it doesn't help either. If you need to build an XML document, `SimpleXMLElement` can be used only to add nodes and attributes and save the document as XML. `DOMDocument` is more flexible, it also allows node replacements and removals. It can edit an existing document too (`SimpleXMLElement` cannot).

Answer (score 0):

When embed XML, always there are many problems :( try this:

Change

```
$dom->loadXML($xmlAusgabe = $xml->asXML());
```

by

```
$xmlAusgabe = $xml->asXML();
$xmlAusgabe = mb_convert_encoding( $xmlAusgabe, 'HTML-ENTITIES',  'UTF-8') ;
$dom->loadXML( $xmlAusgabe );
```

Then  **check encoding and fileencoding is utf8**. If you use vim editor:

```
set encoding=utf-8
set fileencoding=utf-8
```

**UPDATE**

```
libxml_use_internal_errors( FALSE );

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><Root/>');

$data->addChild('NAME', mb_convert_encoding( $variable, 'HTML-ENTITIES',  'UTF-8') );

$xmlAusgabe = $xml->asXML();

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML( $xmlAusgabe );
$dom->save('../test.xml');
```

I check this code and run. To print error use:

```
libxml_get_errors()
```

Comment: thank you for your help, but it doesn't work.
There is still no output in this node:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>`
`<Root>`
`<TEST/>`
`</Root>`

Comment: If you embed HTML maybe use CDATA tag